# CakePHP auth component redirects to login after logOUT

Tags: cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.0

I'm getting started with CakePHP and I'm having a problem setting up the Auth component. **Every time a user logs out, cake is redirecting them back to login.**
You will see that I'm trying to delete/unset some cookies during logout(). This is because I'm setting up a single sign on with a Wordpress site, so I want the user to be logged out of both sites.

My AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {    

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Cookie',
    'Auth'      => array(
        'loginRedirect'     => array('controller' => 'questions', 'action' => 'index'), 
        'logoutRedirect'    => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')            
    )
);
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'login', 'logout', 'display');
}
}
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout', 'login');
}
```

...

```
public function login() {
//who cares
}

public function logout() {

    $wp_cookie = grab_wp_cookie(); //this grabs a specific cookie
    $cookie_name = (isset($wp_cookie['name'])) ? $wp_cookie['name'] : NULL;
      //NONE OF THESE WORK...
    $this->Cookie->write($cookie_name, '', false, time()-3600);
    $this->Cookie->delete($cookie_name);
    $this->Cookie->destroy();

    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Comment: Is it that you want to redirect to a different page on logout?

Comment: Ideally I would redirect after logout, but I don't really care. Right now, it triggers my logIN action which results in the user staying logged in even after the redirection. It's completely confusing to me why the login action should have any involvement in the logout process (example.com/users/logout/)

Comment: Have you tried just using the following line in your `logout()` function?  Last time I was working on a test project... I only used this line: `$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());`  Unless you specifically need those cookie-related lines above...

Comment: I do need the cookie lines because I have to sign out of the Wordpress site at the same time. I'm not sure if those lines have anything to do with the problem anyway. I'll test with them commented out just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have access to the page without being logged. (you can try it accessing to the URL without being logged just to check it)

The solution is to add this `beforeFilter` function at your PagesController:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I pass to the beforeFilter in the PagesController? Also, is it confusing that a non-logged user CAN visit the homepage, which is where logout redirects to?

Answer (score 0):

the PagesController would take the beforeFilter of the AppController. What I might do is this:

```
/**
 * GET /users/logout
 */
public function logout() {
    $this->Auth->logout();
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
}
```

You don't need an allow on logout because logout doesn't have a view.  Your app controller beforeFilter should look as follows:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'display');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

Found the snippet in:
[Simple Authentication and Authorization Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

And don't forget to remove "Login" & "logOut" from beforeFilter.